# Conditionally check radio in angular

Tags: button, angularjs, binding, radio-button

I have a radio group, a button and a boolean value.  When the button is clicked, if the boolean is true, check one radio button and if it false, check the other.  Not sure how to set up binding for something like that.

### Edit

The situation is a little more complicated it turns out.

The flow goes like this:

1. Presented with 2 buttons one to Buy Now one to Buy in Installments
2. Presented with an upsell

   1. If you clicked buy now, add an "addon" sku to the order items hash
   2. If you clicked buy in installments add an "addon_plan" sku to the items hash

So the different states of the hash look like:

```
//base offer only
order.items = {base_offer: 1}

//base offer with payment plan
order.items = {base_offer_plan: 1}

//accessory kit only if base_offer_plan was not selected
order.items = {accessory_kit: 1}

//accessory kit with plan if user first chose base_offer_plan
order.items = {accessory_kit_plan: 1}
```

Comment: You lost me with the edit.  Not too sure what the hashes should look like.  Can you give an example of the hash with various properties and different stages?

Comment: I will update it, yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `ng-value` and setting the value of the model to that value will check a radio.

`ng-value="true"` will set it to `true` where as value="true" will be the string `'true'` and `true != 'true'`  The checkbox returns `true`/`false` Boolean, not strings.

http://jsfiddle.net/TheSharpieOne/d7yWb/

HTML

```
<input type="radio" name="boolRadio" ng-model="checkboxValue" ng-value="true" />
<input type="radio" name="boolRadio" ng-model="checkboxValue" ng-value="false" />
<input type="submit" ng-click="updateValue()" />
<input type="checkbox" name="bool" ng-model="checkbox" />
```

Controller:

```
function myCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.checkbox = false;
    $scope.updateValue = function(){
        $scope.checkboxValue = $scope.checkbox;
    }
}
```

We set the default checkbox to false as it would be undefined and clicking submit would not set the radio properly at the start.

You could make this instant, as soon as they checked the box by removing the updateValue function and setting the radio's models to checkbox directly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample of how I handled a similar scenario... notice ng-class being used in the directive you'd probably want to use ng-checked but do something similar... in my case I end up with two buttons that act as a toggle for Yes No questions:

```
directive('buttonsRadio', [function()
{
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {model: '=', options: '='},
        controller: function($scope)
        {
            $scope.activate = function(option) {
                $scope.model = option;
            }
        },
        template: "<div class='btn-group' data-toggle='buttons-radio'><div ng-repeat='option in options track by option.optionId'><button type='button' class='btn' ng-class='{active: option.optionId==model.optionId}' ng-click='activate(option)'>{{option.name}}</button><br></div></div>"
    }
}])
```

To note I didn't properly setup ng-model here so it will update to the outside and works for my purposes but might not be right.  There's documentation specifically on integrating with ng-model I've used elsewhere like:

```
   // view -> model
   // bit of jQuery in this case to handle async geocoding results
   $(iElement).geocomplete().bind("geocode:result", function(event, result){
       ctrl.$setViewValue(result.formatted_address);
       console.log(result.formatted_address);
       scope.$emit("geocodeResultComplete", result); //use this event to update a google map
    });

    // model -> view
    ctrl.$render = function() {
       iElement.val(ctrl.$viewValue);
    };

    // load init value from DOM
    //ctrl.$setViewValue(iElement.val());
```